# Between the cardano-graphql and cardano-rosetta APIs, which one is recommended for apps and dapps integration?

Tags: api, integration, cardano-graphql

From what I understand, [cardano-graphql](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql) as well as [cardano-rosetta](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-rosetta) APIs enable interaction with the Cardano blockchain. Which of these is recommended for developing apps/dapps that interact with Cardano? Will the Rosetta API be a more comprehensive solution given rosetta is a blockchain specific standard?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your dApp.

[Cardano Rosetta](https://www.rosetta-api.org/docs/data_api_introduction.html) is build by and for exchanges and [Cardano GraphQL](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-graphql/) is more universal.

Review both APIs to make the best decision.

Comment: You can also add Ogmios to the mix, as it's more reliable than Cardano GraphQL for some things, like submitting transactions.